# DNN: losing login session after home page

Tags: session, authentication, dotnetnuke

I have a DNN server with many portals on it.  Of all the separate portals (site), one seems to have a strange login/session issue.  On the site in question, if you log in as a host OR administrator, you (per usual) get redirected to the home page, the site is in EDIT mode, and you can see the "manage" buttons all over.  You can edit the page/modules, see the admin menu at the top of the site (Admin, Modules, Pages, etc), and things work normally.

If you then navigate to any other page on the site, the login session seems to become lost and you are no longer logged in.  At that point, if you login, the session remains in place on all pages on the site.

It does not seem to matter if you do or do not use "Remember Login" during login.  It only happens on this one portal on our DNN site (separate portals, it's not a parent/child site), and there are no unique modules or scripts on this site that we aren't using on other sites.  The problem exists in IE 10, 9 and 8 as well as the most current release of Chrome.  Using the console debugger in Chrome and IE, I don't see anything unusual.

Thoughts?  Suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the PORTALALIASES for that Portal, see if you have multiple aliases defined, and if by chance one is incorrect.

Comment: Chris, thank you so much.  You are a god among men when it comes to .net and dnn.  I read your blog and articles all over the place and have been so helpful to my business and endeavours!  Nice to interact directly with you!  Long story short, I added the www. alias to the already existing xyz.com, changed to "Redirect", and it works perfect now!  THANK YOU SO MUCH for the tip and keep up the great work!

Comment: Glad that worked out for you Ted. I should have mentioned the WWW thing as that happens on a few of my sites if I am not careful :D